# I can’t remove empty space above my header

Tags: html, css

`margin-top: 0`, `padding` and other things didn’t help to remove empty space above my header.

```css
header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: black;
  font-family: calibri sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.headerlist li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  padding: 15px;
}

.headerlist li>a:link {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <ul class="headerlist">
      there was some li lines
    </ul>
  </header>
</body>
```

I expected no empty space above the header but it’s there.

Comment: It’s the [`<ul>`’s margin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clV6M.png). Please use your dev-tools and look at the box model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `margin:0` to your `ul` element *(it has default margin values)*

```css
header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: black;
  font-family: calibri sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
}

html,
body,
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.headerlist li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  padding: 15px;
}

.headerlist li>a:link {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <ul class="headerlist">
      there was some li lines
    </ul>
  </header>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works well now!

Answer (score 0):

Need to do below things to fix this,

1. Need to add `clear` property to the `ul` element as we have made `li` as a floating element.

   .headerlist:after, .headerlist:before {
       content: " ";
       display: table;
       clear: both;
   }
2. There is a default margin value added for the `ul` element, need to remove it.
3. Need not specify height for the header, it will automatically allocate the height based on its child elements.

Please refer the below snippet.

```css
header {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  font-family: calibri sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.headerlist:after, .headerlist:before {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
.headerlist {
  margin: 0;
 }
.headerlist li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  padding: 15px;
}

.headerlist li>a:link {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <ul class="headerlist">
      <li>100</li>
      <li>200</li>
      <li>300</li>
      <li>400</li>
    </ul>
  </header>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it's way more complicated and there are things such as: after (before), content that I wasn't practiced these yet